# HMACSHA256 Returning Incorrect Value

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

I am new to cryptography however I need to use HMACSHA256 to has a message.

I wrote a test method to test my hash method. I used online generators to hash the word: Paul and they all have the same base64 value, however when I do it using the code below, I get a different value. I tried using different encodings but I can't get back the value, can you let me know where I maybe going wrong?

```
[TestClass]
public class HashGeneratorUnitTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        string message = "Paul";
        //Pass a string to method.
        string hashedMessage = ShaGenerator.GetHash(message);
        Assert.AreEqual("gYtcxfIdPm5OYHHAYpRSjURZUCIhhEbYt5ME0rdmMno=",
            hashedMessage);
    }
}

public static class ShaGenerator
{
    public static string GetHash(string message, string secret = "")
    {
        var enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] secretBytes = enc.GetBytes(secret);
        byte[] messageBytes = enc.GetBytes(message);

        using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(secretBytes))
        {
            byte[] hashedBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
            string hashedString = Convert.ToBase64String(hashedBytes);
            //Return HMACSHA256 string.
            return hashedString; //returns: "g9gc9FI2RcI3N9ApYePF+si9Uh0p0Q4u2Vm0Wy5qphk="
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web-based generator you are testing against is incorrect.

Your implementation is returning the correct result.

Here is a web-based tool that returns the proper result: https://quickhash.com/

Comment: Thanks for you reply mark, the issue is my method is returning: "g9gc9FI2RcI3N9ApYePF+si9Uh0p0Q4u2Vm0Wy5qphk=" while the online gens including the one you provided returns: "gYtcxfIdPm5OYHHAYpRSjURZUCIhhEbYt5ME0rdmMno="

Comment: https://quickhash.com returns "g9gc9FI2RcI3N9ApYePF+si9Uh0p0Q4u2Vm0Wy5qphk=" for HMAC SHA256 of plaintext "Paul" with an empty key.

Comment: Hi Mark thanks! Didn't see the check box to use HMAC, thought just regular SHA256 was the one to choose. Thanksa gain